# What should be the approach to negotiate a salary raise at the end of my volunteer project?

Tags: salary

I've became father and things got tight on money immediately, even though I had a raise of 33% in April of 2018. I recently took some classes in front-end development to do some freelance work potentially (did not finish those just yet).

But that mindset allowed me to look at my current job differently. And I've seen some opportunity to dramatically reduce copy/paste time and I started developing those with some degree of success (most of the features I'm able to do or had already done).

I estimate that it will save 10-30% of working time for department of 7 people which is seriously understaffed and we will be able to focus on more complex priorities.

Of course I want more money. How would you approach negotiating with your boss on that issue? I work in oilfield service company with very bad balance sheet.

Edit: I realised something important too. Those processes I own now and it will be harder to replace me with someone else.

Comment: Welcome to Workplace SE and congrats on becoming a dad. So If I understand u correctly. U want to change job to front end because it will pay you more and if so do you have a department in ur own company for developers and needing front end?

Comment: better read THIS qa !  heh !  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/93713/22844

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @cookieMonster Thanks! Not really, I want this as a second freelance job for starters. If I like that, I would think of switching careers and I don't have such department. I think I have natural inclination to the IT and front end seems like a lowest requirement entry level to IT. And most of freelance It projects out there is front end development, so should not be much trouble finding it.

Comment: "Those processes I own now and it will be harder to replace me with someone else. " - be careful with that one.  It is often drilled into managers that if someone is irreplaceable, the manager needs to work out how to replace them.  Telling your boss that you've replaced old processes with new ones that only you understand isn't going to go down well.

Answer (score 2):

You automating some tasks will likely be seen as you living up to your increased paycheck, and not necessarily adding extra value worthy of a raise. Recognition? Sure. A bonus? Maybe. A raise? No, since the automation is a one off event.

The way you typically secure raises is by providing outstanding value, and gaining recognition ***over time*** (coming up with a ***number of ways*** to improve efficiency and streamline processes over several years, for example). And I fear that less than one year after gaining a significant raise you probably will not have gained said recognition.

The situation may be different if you happen to be one of the lowest paid employees in the office, or if you can prove that the going market rate for someone with your qualifications is higher than what you're currently making.

In any case, the way you should go about requesting a raise is by setting up a one on one with your manager, and presenting your arguments as to why you deserve one. Outline the benefits you bring to the company, the skills you've gained since April, and the way in which you've become more productive.

List the processes you've been able to automate, and suggest a list of improvements that you could make to other processes.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I will wait till I have enough processes streamlined, then I will ask for a raise.

Comment: @AndreyRassanov - make sure that you get recognition for your work. Once you've automated one small process on your own, document the benefits, and your other ideas. Then go to your boss and outline your achievements and suggestions. For one thing, maybe management will be opposed to you making any chances at all. Or maybe they will want you to prioritize certain work / focus on the upgrades /  split your time between your regular duties and the automation. Don't simply plug away at this without bringing your boss into the loop.

Answer (score -3):

> Of course I want more money. How would you approach negotiating with your boss on that issue? I work in oilfield service company with very bad balance sheet.

1. RUN, that's RUN to your boss as soon as you see them this mornng, and LOUDLY AND EXCITEDLY - AS IF IT IS NEWS yell in all caps

> "BOSS, GREAT NEWS - I'VE JUST FOUND A WAY TO AUTOMATE {insert something very specific} AND ALSO {insert something very specific} WE HAVE TO GET TO WORK ON THIS STRAIGHT AWAY, IT WILL SAVE {use specific team names} THREE DAYS A WEEK. WE HAVE TO START IMMEDIATELY OMG WTF WHOA"

Do this now, loudly, and in a "BREAKING NEWS OMG WTF" manner.

2. Actually do it.  Hopefully it will take you as few weeks as possible.

Now the good part

## Once you have *finished* this, I personally guarantee you will make much more money.

You will either (A) boss will willingly and happily give you much more money or (B) in one day find a new job with much more money.

## It's important to realize the ONLY way you will get MORE money is to FINISH this project.

Once you FINISH it you WILL get MORE money.  If you DO NOT finish it you WILL NOT get more money.  You WILL NOT get more money now, tomorrow or any day until you finish it.

Once you FINISH it you WILL get MORE money.

I'm happy for you!

Isn't fatherhood great?

Note:

> with very bad balance sheet

1. that is just weird
2. never work for companies with bad balance sheets
3. given point 2, you may want to leave. the *best and in fact only way* to do that is finish your awesome project discussed here.  Enjoy

Comment: You're guaranteeing a lot of things which you have no way of knowing will actually happen. Sure, the OP may play up the automation and translate it into a raise, but if he isn't seen to be providing value on an ongoing basis then he's also going to stand out as ***overpaid*** (thus painting a target on his back). As for him finding a better paying job once he's automated a process ... that's a bit of stretch. One process improvement does not necessarily translate to a marketable skill worthy of more pay (market rates matter). Your post reads like an internet add.

Comment: in the oil service scene, if you can demonstrate automation -> saving, you're golden

Comment: @fattie It's just hard to name that significant, since only automation is for 7 people. But that mindset shift already had me thinking more and more ideas of "what" and "how". And it keeps on adding up faster than I'm able to program.

Comment: I can only give you my opinion:  it is significant and awesome.  (If you get it finished!)